# Laravel service container - registering an object shared to all services

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to register to the container an Uuid and i have tried to retrive it from a route controller more than once, but the uuid value is not the first registered.

Can anyone help me to understand?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function boot()
    {   
        if(App::bound('conf')==NULL)
            App::instance('conf', Uuid::generate()->string);
    }
}

class InstanceController extends Controller
{
    public function getUuid()
    {
        return App::make('conf');
    }   
}
```

I need to register an unique value or object that will be accessible to all.

I have also tried to put this code:

```
config(['uuid' => Uuid::generate()->string]);
```

in Laravel command handle method:

```
class RegisteredInstances extends Command
{
    public function handle()
    {
        config(['uuid' => Uuid::generate()->string]);
    }
}
```

and execute it, but when i try to retrive the uuid from a service, the response is null.

Now i have registered a laravel command that do this:

```
class RegisteredInstances extends Command
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function handle()
    {
        if(App::bound('conf')==NULL)
            App::instance('conf', Uuid::generate()->string);

        if(config('uuid2')==NULL)
            config(['uuid2' => Uuid::generate()->string]);
    }
}
```

A task every minute execute this command and i try to retrive the uuid from a service controller like this:

```
class InstanceController extends Controller
{
    public function getUuid()
    {
        return App::make('conf');
    }

    public function getUuid()
    {
        return config('uuid2');
    }     
}
```

The problem, in this case, is that the controller return NULL:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use laravel [Configuration (accessing-configuration-values)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) with **AppServiceProvider**

Example:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   public function boot()
   { 
       config([ 'theconfig.uuid' => $class_here->UUID ]);
   }
}
```

Then to use it, call

```
config('theconfig.uuid');
```

anywhere in the program

Comment: The problem is that the AppServiceProvider boot() function is recalled whenever i try to call a controller services than the Uuid is generated again.
I tried to put this check: if(config('uuid')==NULL) in AppServiceProvider boot() and it's is ever true;

Answer (score 0):

Is this in Laravel 4? I haven't seen the `App::instance` markup before, but I found it in [Laravel 4.2 docs for the IoC Container](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc).

This looks like a case for using a singleton. You can use this to ensure that `conf` is only resolved once. Looking at 4.2 docs, you could define your singleton as follows.

```
App::singleton('conf', function()
{
    return Uuid::generate()->string;
});
```

Comment: I have tried it, I have defined a singleton in a laravel provider, but when I try to get the stored string with a controller, the uuid returned is ever different whenever I call the service controller. I use laravel 5.8